# Boolean Substitution Comaprision Not Giving Proper OUTOPUT

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a plsql code in which  I have declared variable , but when i change the comparison operator then code is not working properly like as I defined below

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    v_num1   number(10);
    v_num2     number(10);
    v_num3      number(10);
    v_num4      number(10);

    lowrec      boolean:=FALSE;
BEGIN   
    v_num3 := 34;
    v_num4:=3;

    lowrec :=(v_num3>v_num4);

    IF lowrec then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The record is '||v_num3 ||' smaller than '||v_num4 ||' ' ||sys.diutil.bool_to_int(lowrec));
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The record is '||v_num3||' higher than '||v_num4 ||' '||sys.diutil.bool_to_int(lowrec));
    END IF;

END;


OUTPUT: 
The record is 34 smaller than 3 1

passed value are 34 and 3 but it is showing 34 is smaller than 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the `dbms_output` messages between `IF` and `ELSE`

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
     v_num1 NUMBER(10);
     v_num2 NUMBER(10);
     v_num3 NUMBER(10);
     v_num4 NUMBER(10);
     lowrec BOOLEAN := false;
BEGIN
     v_num3 := 34;
      v_num4 := 3;

    lowrec := (v_num3 > v_num4 );
     IF lowrec THEN dbms_output.put_line('The record is '
                               || v_num3
                               || ' higher than '
                               || v_num4
                               ||' '|| sys.diutil.bool_to_int(lowrec));
     ELSE dbms_output.put_line('The record is '
                                       || v_num3
                                       || ' smaller than '|| v_num4  --or equal to ?
                                       || ' '
                                       || sys.diutil.bool_to_int(lowrec));
     END IF;

END;
/

The record is 34 higher than 3 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: @Suman : What error are you talking about? It does not throw any error. If you change the numbers and compare them with a different operator, the truth value should reverse isn't it? Hence the other output message is displayed. I hope you have sufficient knowledge to understand boolean logic. But, I don't see what you're trying to achieve here anyway!

Comment: Yes , **Thank a lot** , i changed the values but forget in swapping the logic so that error occurred . #Solved #Worked